# Concrete5 and jVector map

Tags: javascript, concrete5, jvectormap

I am using [jvector maps](http://jvectormap.com/) map on a clients website that they know want me to convert to Concrete5 so they can edit themselves. all was going fine until I tried to recreate the page I use jVector maps. when I pop in the following script that allows me to use the map and colour different sections when hovered stops the "edit" part of the concrete5 admin section fromworking, meaning I can't either see the edit bar/button or if I'm already in edit mode, cant actually click on the editable areas. here is the script I'm talking about:

```
$(function(){
      $('#world-map').vectorMap({
            map: 'world_merc_en',
            backgroundColor:'#FFF',
            onRegionClick: function(event, code) {
              if (code === 'US') {
                  window.location = 'espiner/index.php/global-medical-partners'
              }else if (code === 'CA') {
                  window.location = 'espiner/index.php/medivogue'
              }else if (code === 'ES') {
                  window.location = 'espiner/index.php/prim'
              }else if (code === 'GB') {
                  window.location = 'espiner/index.php/fannin'
              }else if (code === 'NO') {
                  window.location = 'espiner/index.php/endotech'
              }else if (code === 'FI') {
                  window.location = 'espiner/index.php/endotec-oy'
              } else if (code === 'NL') {
                  window.location = 'espiner/index.php/medicor'
              }else if (code === 'DE') {
                  window.location = 'espiner/index.php/ifm-gerbershagen'
              }else if (code === 'PL') {
                  window.location = 'espiner/index.php/surg-tech'
              }else if (code === 'CH') {
                  window.location = 'espiner/index.php/rey-medical'
              }else if (code === 'AT') {
                  window.location = 'espiner/index.php/dach-medical-group-gmbh'
              }else if (code === 'IT') {
                  window.location = 'espiner/index.php/ab-medica-Spa'
              }else if (code === 'HR') {
                  window.location = 'espiner/index.php/doctum'
              }else if (code === 'GR') {
                  window.location = 'espiner/index.php/surgilife-ltd'
              }else if (code === 'SA') {
                  window.location = 'espiner/index.php/trustmed'
              }else if (code === 'CN') {
                  window.location = 'espiner/index.php/medical-distrubutor-alliance'
              }else if (code === 'MY') {
                  window.location = 'espiner/index.php/wsm-medic-enterprise'
              }else if (code === 'ES') {
                  window.location = 'espiner/index.php/prim'
              }else if (code === 'AU') {
                  window.location = 'espiner/index.php/emt-Healthcare'
              }else if (code === 'NZ') {
                  window.location = 'espiner/index.php/ebos-Healthcare'
              }
            },
            regionStyle: {
                initial: {
                    fill: '#b1b3b6',
                    stroke: '#FFF'
                }
            },
            series: {
              regions: [{
                values: {
                    US:'#002E6D',
                    CA:'#002E6D',
                    ES:'#002E6D',
                    GB:'#002E6D',
                    NO:'#002E6D',
                    FI:'#002E6D',
                    NL:'#002E6D',
                    DE:'#002E6D',
                    PL:'#002E6D',
                    CH:'#002E6D',
                    AT:'#002E6D',
                    IT:'#002E6D',
                    HR:'#002E6D',
                    GR:'#002E6D',
                    SA:'#002E6D',
                    CN:'#002E6D',
                    MY:'#002E6D',
                    AU:'#002E6D',
                    NZ:'#002E6D',       
                    XX:'#002E6D',   
                }
              }]
            }
      });
    });
```

Can anyone help pin point the part that C5 doesn't like, I'm thinking its the actual functions: `$('#world-map').vectorMap({`
but don't know how to get around it.

Answer (score 0):

Very often this problem happens because a script or other piece of code is loading jQuery independently in parallel with C5's jquery. You might want to check that's not the case.